# SOAPUI authentication 1.0

Tags: rest, oauth, soapui

I've been trying to automate a Restful service using SOAPUI for which OAuth 1.0 authentication is required. In this regards, I've the "Access Token" and "Token Secret" keys generated by an internal server and on entering those keys manually in SOAPUI, I've been still getting unauthorized user response whereas the same is working fine using POSTMAN!

Any thoughts or lead would be of great help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe include a screen capture of how you setup authentication on SOAP UI.  You may think you configured it, but if done incorrectly, it won't work.

Comment: In on of my project, we use Groovy to intercept all requests and generate 'authorization' header to achieve auth 1.0

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was able to figure that out and now I'm able to verify the oatuh and retrieve the data. Any thoughts on automating the process?

Comment: @NghiaDo Can you please let me know how you're automating it? As of now i'm manually extracting the keys from a server and passing those to SOAPUI.. But I wish to get that automated as well. Any reference?

Comment: @UmeshKumar Yes, it is possible to write a script inside SOAP UI that can do an OAuth login.  Search around and you will find examples.  The SmartBear website is a good resource for this.